# Check if the elements in array have been connected into a pair in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve, maybe you can help.

There is an array I have. E.g. `['@dog','@cat','@mouse']`

I want to reiterate through each value in that array and connect it to all the other values in that same array (through building a DB query).

However, because I'll be writing that in a database I need to avoid duplicates.

So if the `@cat` has been already connected to `@mouse` then by the time my `for` statement reaches the `@mouse` i want it to skip adding connection to `@cat` (and also to `@dog` because it was already connected on the first iteration to `@mouse`.

I've been trying with `for` loops, such as

```
for (var i=0; i<animals.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j<animals.length; j++) {
        if (animals[i] !== animals[j]) {
            // adds connection between animals[i] and animals[j]
        }
    }
}
```

But what's the best way to implement a check of the already existing pairs? (where it doesn't matter which element is the first, which is the second - e.g. my graph is not unidirectional).

This especially becomes a problem if I'm going to have more than 4 elements in the array...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: could you please, share the expected output as I got confused

Comment: just as  @mGouda says. I tried understanding your question, but is all very confusing, specially for the double for on the same variable `animals`

Comment: Why on earth would you have a KEY with the same name of a VALUE? you're apparently looping into a dimentional array (like a matrix), maybe you want to just loop into the array and check for duplicates? animals[i] is the KEY, while animals[j] is the current value.

Comment: The expected output would be something like 

query =+ animals[i] + ' and ' animals[j] + ' ';

in the end I don't want to have pairs repeating themselves.

Comment: Are you trying to just connect all entries with each other without creating the reverse links? So `Cat -> Mouse` but not `Mouse -> Cat`? In that case, just make your inner loop `for (var j = i + 1; i < animals.length; i++)`

Comment: can this array have duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<animals.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j<i; j++) {
        if (animals[i] !== animals[j]) {
            // adds connection between animals[i] and animals[j]
        }
    }
}
```

This way, each element of the array is only compared against those before it in the array. I think this is much closer to what you want.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much for your very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop, you only want to make connections to elements not yet visited by the outer loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<animals.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i+1; j<animals.length; j++) {
//               ^^^
        // adds connection between animals[i] and animals[j]
    }
}
```

That way you won't get duplicate edges (assuming that `animals` itself is duplicate-free)